# Want to create sonar plugin to parse txt file

Tags: sonarqube

I want to write a sonar plugin which can parse a txt file in case some specific words eg abusive word come in that file it marks it mark it’s as critical warning, if some other category of words appears in document it marks it as moderate etc.

We are using Sonar for our C++,Java code and also want to leverage for txt file parsing.
We are ready to make our own plugin or customize any existing plugin.
Can anyone please help me in proceeding with the same or give some ideas how to proceed with the same.

Thanks
Saurabh

Answer (score 1):

This question was subsequently discussed on the Sonar developers mailing list. You can read that thread here:  http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/sonar-dev-Want-to-create-sonar-plugin-to-parse-txt-file-Can-someone-please-help-tp5025700.html

Spoilers:

- A text language plugin implementation was built as part of the conversation and is attached to this post: http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/sonar-dev-Want-to-create-sonar-plugin-to-parse-txt-file-Can-someone-please-help-tp5025700p5025936.html
- The plugin currently doesn't seem to be documented on SonarQube's site. Not sure why but that suggests to me that it may not be a very mature plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the material that will be useful to you in order to write your own SonarQube plugin:

1. [Coding a Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Coding+a+Plugin) documentation
2. [Sample Plugin](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/sonar-reference-plugin) that you can use to bootstrap your plugin. Most notably, check the [Sensor and Decorator classes](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/sonar-reference-plugin/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sonar/reference/batch).